# How can I stop Views from eating my query strings when rewriting a link?

Tags: views

I have a view and I am trying to rewrite the links by appending a query string.

`[name_1]` is the name of the location.  The various values for `age[]` are the taxonomy term IDs for an exposed filter, and `friends` is a profile field.

Under **Rewrite results**, I have checked *Output this field as a link*.  This is my link:

```
location/[name_1]?age[]=27&age[]=31&age[]=35&age[]=39&age[]=43&age[]=44&friends=1
```

When I cut and paste the query string into the URL bar, it works fine.  However, when I tell views to rewrite the string I get URLs that look like this:

```
location/mexico?friends=1&age[]=44
```

This gives me no results and a broken view.

It appears that the query strings are processed in reverse, and it only accepts the first value for `age[]`-- even though when I type the same thing into the URL bar it is OK.

I tried replacing the symbols in the rewriting string like this:

```
location/[name_1]age%5B%5D=27&age%5B%5D=31&age%5B%5D=35&age%5B%5D=39&age%5B%5D=43&age%5B%5D=44&friends=1
```

Now, when I access the view, I no longer get an error, but none of the age (taxonomy term) checkboxes are checked and the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/en/location/mexico?age%255b%255d=44&friends=1
```

So, clearly most of the `age[]` values are still disappearing for some reason.

How can I rewrite the query string so that views outputs it properly?

EDIT: According to Jimajamma's comment, D6 Views suggests using `%5B%5D`, as I have already tried (I'm on D7).  `&#91;&#93;` didn't work for me either (this combo doesn't even work in the URL bar).  Perhaps this is a bug in Views?

EDIT 2: As per the answers, this appears to be a bug in Drupal Core/Views, not a configuration error.  So I attempted to avoid using Views *rewrite results output as a link* feature and instead just *rewrite results* and code the link in HTML.

The only problem with this approach is that some of the terms have spaces in their names, and I was using the *convert spaces to dashes* option provided by the *output as a link* setting to get around this.  So now the links for terms that have no spaces work properly, but the links for terms with spaces are broken...

Comment: Just a quick question - are you sure it's in views? The same link outputted via l() works all right? I don't see any place in views that could create this behaviour (that does not prove anything, I just want a little cross-test).

Comment: @Molot Using `l()`, the special characters ([]?) get garbled like this `location/mexico%3Fage%3D27%26age%3D31%26age%3D35%26age%3D39%26age%3D43%26age%3D44%26friends%3D1`.  However, at least in this case nothing is cut from the link as it is in Views.

Comment: Magic. I'll try to look again, but you encountered something either to deep or to obvious for me to spot.

Comment: I am gonna go out on a betting limb here and suggest that views is thinking your variable arrays are actually token replacements, eg the []s are confusing it and it is thing [....everything between the first one and the last...] is a field to be replaced/substituted and then not finding anything, collapsing it into just what it could decypher.

Comment: @Jimajamma Ok, sounds reasonable.  So how might I get around that?

Comment: Back here in d6landia, I have the following warning in Views `If you would like to have the characters %5B and %5D please use the html entity codes '%5B' or '%5D' or they will get replaced with empty space.` Those are [ and ] so I'd try those or &#91; / &#93; etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is not with views. What views does is it calls `drupal_get_query_array` to build the query array. And as of now `drupal_get_query_array` does not support same name array in the query params. All it does is just explodes the query and saves it as follows;

```
$result[$param[0]] = isset($param[1]) ? rawurldecode($param[1]) : '';
```

So if you see the see it is going to be overridden and it is just going to store

```
array ('age' => 44, 'friends' => 1)
```

I have created a ticket and reported this issue and attached a patch as well at https://drupal.org/node/2023815

The same patch should work for 7.x as well.

**Alternatives**

So [Views php](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) / Custom module looks like a good alternative without hacking the core.

Comment: Awarding you the bounty for filing this as a bug against core and contributing a patch.  Thanks for looking into this and getting the ball rolling!

Answer (score 0):

Odd that VIEWS is doing that. Here's a fresh approach for you.

My recommendation would be to use the [views_php](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

1. install/enable views_php, Then
2. exclude the field rather than rewriting it as a link.
3. add field "global php" to the view [not sure i got that name right, but it has php in it]
4. in that php field write a small script to take the $data attributes and use the drupal [l() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to let Drupal build the url.

Mind you.... The better solution would be to hook into this view and programmatically create the link rather than using views_php to run the eval() on each result. But nonetheless, the views_php module does exist for these quick-n-dirty use cases where the site builder may not be comfortable writing a custom module to hook into Views. Some one else may post the custom module solution here, OR maybe I will later.

Comment: I can write a custom module, but isn't there some way to get Views to support query strings out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

user l() like

```
<?php
l(<Title>,<URL|URI>, 
    array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'my-id', 
            'class' => 'my-class'
        ), 
        'query' => array(  /* You Want this */
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'foo1' => 'bar1',
        ), 
        'fragment' => 'refresh',
        'html' => TRUE
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: How do I use this in Views?  My question is about using a views token plus a query string (that should not be substituted as a token).